# WordPress - How to hide a div if the condition of a variable is not met?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm using a series of variables to output data in my loop. I have one, `$profile`, that pulls the featured image from my custom post type. This variable is inside of a div, I want it so that if there is no featured image set, the div doesn't display. I have CSS on this div, so it creates weird spacing of content if there isn't an image.

Here's my function:

```
function management_team_query() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'management-team',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
    );
    $team_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $team_query->have_posts() ) :

        $mtRepeat = get_field('mt_repeater', 'options' );
        $mtCount = 1;

        $html_out = '<article class="team-member box-center">';
        // $html_out .= '<div class="row">';
        while ( $team_query->have_posts() ) :
            $team_query->the_post();

            // If $mtRepeat exists
            if ($mtRepeat) :
                // Check Repeater field for a corresponding position
                foreach ($mtRepeat as $item):
                    $itemPosition = $item['mt_position'];
                    if ($itemPosition == $mtCount):
                        // if the positions match (ex: item position is n and current mtCount is n
                        // Display the image
                    $itemImage = $item['mt_photo'];
                        $html_out .= 
                            '<div class="meta-team box vc_col-sm-5 animation-element slide-in in-view">
                                <div class="hang">
                                    <img src="' . $itemImage . '" />
                                </div>
                            </div>';
                        // Increase the mtCount
                        $mtCount++;
                    endif;
                endforeach;
            endif;

            $role = get_field( "role" );
            $name = get_field( "team_member_name" );
            $bio = get_field( "bio" );
            $profile = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
            // echo $profile[0];
            $flip = get_field( "contact_info" );
            // Do stuff with each post here
        $html_out .= 
        '<div class="meta-team box vc_col-sm-5 vc_col-lg-offset-1">
            <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle("hover");">
                <div class="flipper">
                    <div class="front">
                        <h6>' . $role . '</h6>' . '<h4>' . $name . '</h4>' . $bio . '
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <div class="meta-team-img" style="background: url(' . $profile[0] .') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"></div>
                        <p>' . $flip . '</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
        $mtCount++;
        endwhile;
        // $html_out .= '</div>';
        $html_out .= '</article>';
    else : // No results
        $html_out = "No News Found.";
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $html_out;
}
```

I know most of this code is irrelevant, but I thought I'd include it in so you know  the full thing.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a conditional around the div block. Something like this:

```
$html_out .= 
'<div class="meta-team box vc_col-sm-5 vc_col-lg-offset-1">
    <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle("hover");">
        <div class="flipper">
            <div class="front">
                <h6>' . $role . '</h6>' . '<h4>' . $name . '</h4>' . $bio . '
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                ' . (!empty($profile[0]) ? '<div class="meta-team-img" style="background: url(' . $profile[0] .') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"></div>' : '') . '
                <p>' . $flip . '</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<div class="back">
                        <div class="meta-team-img" style="background: url(' . $profile[0] .') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"></div>
                        <p>' . $flip . '</p>
                    </div>
```

to :

```
     <div class="back">'.
     ((!isset($profile[0]) || empty($profile[0]))? '': 
'<div class="meta-team-img" style="background: url(' . $profile[0] .') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"></div>' ).        
                                '<p>' . $flip . '</p>
                            </div>
```

(check if $profile[0] exists and is not empty)

Answer (score 0):

Split up the $html_out variable and add a conditional statement to concatenate the div only if it exists.

For example

(Edited)

```
$html_out .= '<div class="meta-team box vc_col-sm-5 vc_col-lg-offset-1">';

$html_out .= '<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle("hover");">'; 
$html_out .= '<div class="flipper">'; 
$html_out .= '<div class="front"> <h6>' . $role . '</h6>' . '<h4>' . $name . '</h4>' . $bio . '</div>'; 
$html_out .= '<div class="back">';

if (!empty($profile[0]))
{
    $html_out .= '<div class="meta-team-img" style="background: url(' . $profile[0] .') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"></div>';        
}

$html_out .= '<p>' . $flip . '</p>';
$html_out .= '</div></div></div></div>';
```

Inserted into your function it should be like this:

```
function management_team_query() {

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'management-team',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
    );

    $team_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $team_query->have_posts() ) :

        $mtRepeat = get_field('mt_repeater', 'options' );
        $mtCount = 1;

        $html_out = '<article class="team-member box-center">';
        // $html_out .= '<div class="row">';
        while ( $team_query->have_posts() ) :
            $team_query->the_post();

            // If $mtRepeat exists
            if ($mtRepeat) :
                // Check Repeater field for a corresponding position
                foreach ($mtRepeat as $item):
                    $itemPosition = $item['mt_position'];
                    if ($itemPosition == $mtCount):
                        // if the positions match (ex: item position is n and current mtCount is n
                        // Display the image
                    $itemImage = $item['mt_photo'];
                        $html_out .= 
                            '<div class="meta-team box vc_col-sm-5 animation-element slide-in in-view">
                                <div class="hang">
                                    <img src="' . $itemImage . '" />
                                </div>
                            </div>';
                        // Increase the mtCount
                        $mtCount++;
                    endif;
                endforeach;
            endif;

            $role = get_field( "role" );
            $name = get_field( "team_member_name" );
            $bio = get_field( "bio" );
            $profile = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
            // echo $profile[0];
            $flip = get_field( "contact_info" );
            // Do stuff with each post here

            $html_out .= '<div class="meta-team box vc_col-sm-5 vc_col-lg-offset-1">';
            $html_out .= '<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle("hover");">'; 
            $html_out .= '<div class="flipper">'; 
            $html_out .= '<div class="front"> <h6>' . $role . '</h6>' . '<h4>' . $name . '</h4>' . $bio . '</div>'; 
            $html_out .= '<div class="back">';

            if (!empty($profile[0]))
            {
                // This will only be displayed if there is a profile image
                $html_out .= '<div class="meta-team-img" style="background: url(' . $profile[0] .') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"></div>';        
            }

            $html_out .= '<p>' . $flip . '</p>';
            $html_out .= '</div></div></div></div>';

        $mtCount++;
        endwhile;
        // $html_out .= '</div>';
        $html_out .= '</article>';
    else : // No results
        $html_out = "No News Found.";
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $html_out;
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of splitting it into two, but I don't want it to affect the entire `.back` div, just the `.meta-team-img div`. I only want to mess with the image part of it.

Comment: I've moved the conditional around the meta-team-img div and also split the code up further to make it more readable